# deleting labeltext after pressing button with tkinter in Python

Tags: python, tkinter

Hello this is my first question on this platform. I got a problem with tkinter, I have an entry where the user can write a number. If the user writes something else and press save a label appears with "only floats allowed" so far so good. But if the user writes after the label a appears a number an presses yes, the label should be deleted. How can I delete the label after it plots the first time by correcting the entry and pressing save again?
P.s. its my first try to Code a GUI so I'm thankful for other tipps & tricks.

```
import tkinter as tk


parison_window = tk.Tk()
parison_window.title("Create Parison")
parison_window.geometry("1000x1000")
pwt1_lbl = tk.Label(parison_window, text="PWT1")

pwt1_lbl.pack()
pwt1_lbl.place(x=30, y=130)


label = tk.Label(parison_window, text="1")
label.pack()
label.place(x=10, y=140 + 20 )
entry = tk.Entry(parison_window, width=5, justify="center")
entry.pack()
entry.place(x=30, y=140 + 20)

def check_and_save():
    if entry.get():
        try:
            pwt1 = float(entry.get())
            
        except ValueError:
            error_text = tk.Label(parison_window, text="only floats allowed")
            error_text.pack()
            error_text.place(x=150, y=140 + 20 )


save_button = tk.Button(parison_window, text="save", command=check_and_save)
save_button.pack()

parison_window.mainloop()
```

Comment: You can call `.config(text="")` on the Label.

Comment: `pack()` and `place()` (and `grid()`) are different `layout managers`- when you use `place()` then you don't need `pack()`

Comment: if you want to remove text from existing label then you can use `error_text.config(text="")` or `error_text["text"] = ""`. But if you want to create new label when you get new error then you may rather `error_text.destroy()` to remove all widget. But it may need to create global variable for label and use `None` to inform code that label doesn't exists - so you don't have to delete it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to remove text from existing label then you can use `error_text.config(text="")` or `error_text["text"] = ""`.

If you want to remove all widget then you may do `error_text.destroy()`

But all this make problem because widget may not exists in some moments and trying to set text or destroy it may generate error.

You should rather create empty label at start and later only replace text in this label.

```
import tkinter as tk

# --- functions ---  # PEP8: all functions before main code

def check_and_save():
    if entry.get():
        try:
            pwt1 = float(entry.get())
            error_text['text'] = ""
        except ValueError:
            error_text['text'] = "only floats allowed"

# --- main ---

parison_window = tk.Tk()
parison_window.title("Create Parison")
parison_window.geometry("1000x1000")

pwt1_lbl = tk.Label(parison_window, text="PWT1")
pwt1_lbl.place(x=30, y=130)

# ---

label = tk.Label(parison_window, text="1")
label.place(x=10, y=140+20)

entry = tk.Entry(parison_window, width=5, justify="center")
entry.place(x=30, y=140+20)

error_text = tk.Label(parison_window)  # create label with empty text
error_text.place(x=150, y=140+20)

# ---

save_button = tk.Button(parison_window, text="save", command=check_and_save)
save_button.pack()

parison_window.mainloop()
```

[PEP 8 -- Style Guide for Python Code](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/)

---

**BTW:**

`pack()` and `place()` (and `grid()`) are different `layout managers` and when you use `place()` then you don't need `pack()` (and `grid()`)

---

**EDIT:**

Using `destroy()` it would need to use global variable `error_text` with default value `None` at start. And later it would need to check if `error_text` is not `None` and destroy it (and assign again `None`)

```
import tkinter as tk

# --- functions ---  # PEP8: all functions before main code

def check_and_save():
    global error_text  # inform function to assign new value to global variable `error_text` instead of creating local variable `error_text`
    
    if entry.get():
        try:
            pwt1 = float(entry.get())
            if error_text is not None:
                error_text.destroy()
                error_text = None
        except ValueError:
            if error_text is not None:
                error_text.destroy()
                error_text = None
            error_text = tk.Label(parison_window, text="only floats allowed")
            error_text.place(x=150, y=140+20)

# --- main ---

parison_window = tk.Tk()
parison_window.title("Create Parison")
parison_window.geometry("1000x1000")

pwt1_lbl = tk.Label(parison_window, text="PWT1")
pwt1_lbl.place(x=30, y=130)

# ---

label = tk.Label(parison_window, text="1")
label.place(x=10, y=140+20)

entry = tk.Entry(parison_window, width=5, justify="center")
entry.place(x=30, y=140+20)

error_text = None   # global variable with default value

# ---

save_button = tk.Button(parison_window, text="save", command=check_and_save)
save_button.pack()

parison_window.mainloop()
```